# How to know whether View is already on Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

*Sorry for my English*

May be the `View.isInLayout()` method does the same what I want, but it added in Android in `API version 18`, and I use `MIN VERSION == 9` in my app.

What can I do?

At the moment I use the next code to catch the moment, when `view` will be placed on layout, i.e. to catch the moment, when `view` will have actual sizes:

```
public static void runOnViewPlacedOnLayout(final Runnable runnable) {
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(view, this);
                    runnable.run();
                }
           }
    );
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View view, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    } else {
        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}
```

But in my code a `view` may be already placed on `layout`. In that case what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know if a view is added to a layout, you do

`View view = layout.findViewById(int id);`

or

`View view = layout.findViewByTag(Object tag);`

and ...

`if(view != null) ... //view is already added`

Depending on your requirements, you either then call layout.removeView(view) to remove the view and add a new, or update it or do nothing... or whatever you want :)

Comment: or else if `view.getParent()` returns a non-null instance, then `View` is already in layout...

Comment: @GopalRao +1. Your solution is efficient as findViewById(id) does a lookup in view hierarchy.